# Resize UITableView height dynamically

Tags: swift, uitableview, swift3

I am trying to resize the tableview dynamically fixing the size to their content (number of rows). The row heights are stablished to 300 and when I push the button bellow the table I will need to expand his height.

I have tryed to disabled scroll control in uiTableView and put this code in viewDidAppear but I don´t get the correct result:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
            var frame: CGRect = self.tableView.frame;
            frame.size.height = self.tableView.contentSize.height;
            self.tableView.frame = frame;
}
```

I have also tried to implement this method and call them before add a row:

```
func tableView_Auto_Height()
    {
        if(self.tableView.contentSize.height < self.tableView.frame.height){
            var frame: CGRect = self.tableView.frame;
            frame.size.height = self.tableView.contentSize.height;
            self.tableView.frame = frame;
        }
    }
```

I have this scheme view:

[image: components scheme]

Answer (score 0):

Finally I solve the problem adding a view that contains the scrollview (view attach image) and other view before the scroll, and adding this line in the button:

```
let numberForConstraint = CGFloat((detailLines.count + 1)  * 300)
tableHeightConstraint.constant = numberForConstraint
```

Maybe is not the best solution but this solves my problem.

[image]

Comment: 300 is the height configured for my rows